# How to handle multiple remote-notification click in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, viewcontroller, notificationcenter

I am trying to open different view controllers based on `notification` click but when `push notification` is received it automatically runs the controller code in background so when I open the app through app icon/notification from `notification centre` it loads the `view controller` immediately but when multiple notifications are received it loads first notification controller irrespective of whichever notification was tapped.

> Let's say I've got notification with titles "Evening","Morning" and
>   "Night", it should open "Evening View Controller" when "Evening"
>   notification is tapped but it loads "Night View Controller" when I go
>   back it loads "Morning View Controller" and at last it loads "Evening
>   View Controller". Before notification came, I was on Main Controller
>   and then I moved the app into background.

When I tap on "Morning" `notification` it doesn't do anything now.

Earlier I tried using addObserver but result is the same so I move to app delegate.

Here is the app delegate code

```
@interface AppDelegate ()

@end


@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum];

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    // Register for Push Notitications, if running iOS 8 or More

    if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {

        UIUserNotificationType userNotificationTypes = (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert |
                                                        UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
                                                        UIUserNotificationTypeSound);
        UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:userNotificationTypes categories:nil];
        [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
        [application registerForRemoteNotifications];

    } else {
        // Register for Push Notifications before iOS 8

        [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |  UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
    }

    [application setStatusBarHidden:YES];

    return YES;
}

// Handle remote notification registration.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {

    NSLog(@"Device Token %@",[self stringWithDeviceToken:deviceToken]);

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:[self stringWithDeviceToken:deviceToken] forKey:@"registration_id"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)err {

    NSLog(@"Error in registration. Error: %@", err);
}


- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {

    NSDictionary *alertInfo = (NSDictionary *) userInfo[@"aps"][@"alert"];
    NSLog(@"%@",alertInfo);

    NSString *alertID = [userInfo valueForKey:@"alertid"];


    if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground) {

        [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber + 1;

        NSLog(@"Background Mode");
        NSString *title = alertInfo[@"title"];

        [self openViewController:title];
    }

    if(application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive){

        NSLog(@"Active Mode");
           }

    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
    [self performSelector:@selector(sendAckRequest:) withObject:alertID];
}


- (void)openViewController:(NSString *)notificationTitle{

    NSDictionary * userDict = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"loginUser"];

    if([notificationTitle isEqualToString:@"Exercise"]){

    UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;

    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];

    Excercise *excerciseController = (Excercise*)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"Excercise"];       
    [navigationController pushViewController:excerciseController animated:YES];
    //[navigationController presentViewController:excerciseController animated:YES completion:nil];

    }else if([notificationTitle isEqualToString:@"Weight"]){

        UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;

        UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];

        Weight *weightController = (Weight*)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"Weight"];           
       [navigationController pushViewController:weightController animated:YES];

        //[navigationController presentViewController:weightController animated:YES completion:nil];

    }else if([notificationTitle isEqualToString:@"MCQ"]){

        UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;

        UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];

        QuestionOfTheDay *questionController = (QuestionOfTheDay*)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"QuestionOfTheDay"];
        questionController.self.dictUser = userDict;
        [navigationController pushViewController:questionController animated:YES]
    }
}

-(void)sendAckRequest:(NSString *)alertID {

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSString *userID =[[defaults objectForKey:@"loginUser"]objectForKey:@"UserId"];
    NSString *serverRegistrationID = [defaults objectForKey:@"server_registration_id"];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];

    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];
    NSString *currentDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

    //NSDate *currentDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:currentDateString];

    //NSDictionary *parameter = @{@"ReminderDateTime":currentDateString};

    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@/%@/%@/?ReminderDateTime=%@",sendNotificationAck,userID,serverRegistrationID,alertID,currentDateString];


    NSLog(@"url: %@",url);

    [manager GET:url parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation * _Nonnull operation, id  _Nonnull responseObject) {

        if(operation.response.statusCode == 200)
            NSLog(@"Notification Acknowledged");
        else
            NSLog(@"Notification failed to acknowledge");

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation * _Nullable operation, NSError * _Nonnull error) {

        NSLog(@"error: %@",[error localizedDescription]);
    }];
}

- (NSString *)stringWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {

    const char *data = [deviceToken bytes];

    NSMutableString *token = [NSMutableString string];

    for (int i = 0; i < [deviceToken length]; i++) {

        [token appendFormat:@"%02.2hhX", data[i]];
    }

    return token;
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.

    if([UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber!=0)
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber - 1;
}

@end
```

Comment: You can use boolean values to handle it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, your `Remote Notification` background mode is enabled, so the notifications get handled in the background. Now the bug is, whenever a notification comes, you push a viewController to the viewController stack, that's why you see three viewControllers stacked.

Second, `didReceiveRemoteNotification` can be called/handled in different states. `StateBackground` if the app is in background, `StateInactive` if user tap the notification from Notification Center, `StateForeground` if the app is in foreground. You add a check only push the viewController in `StateBackground`, that's why you don't see any change when tap the notification.

Comment: Does that mean if i add the navigation code in `StateInactive` it will work? @dichen

Comment: Add StateInactive check will handle the case when you tap the notification.  But be careful about handle it multiple times, once for background and once for inactive.  You might need a flag that check if the destination viewController is already displayed or not.

Comment: I will check that but earlier i was using `StateBackground` and it was not going when notification tapped. I will try with `StateInactive` and let you know. Shall i use direct view controller code or add observer and try?

Comment: Sorry I don't follow this, "Shall i use direct view controller code or add observer and try?"

Comment: Shall i use navigation controller in app delegate inside `StateInActive` or `addObserver` instead of navigation controller

Comment: Just do it in the applicationDelegate.  I don't know what was the code of your addObserver.  Any update?

Comment: I will do that tomorrow and let you know

Comment: Looks like your idea is working. I will test more and accept it. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 1):

For this it is needed to check applicationstate in `didReceiveRemoteNotification` method . Here is code :

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {

 //recieved notification
    if ( application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive ){
        // app was already in the foreground
        UIViewController* topViewController = [self.navigationController topViewController];
        if ([topViewController isKindOfClass:[HomeVC class]]) {
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"getUpdatedServiceData" object:nil];
        }
    }
}
```

in HomeVC You need to create notificate **getUpdatedServiceData** and within this method push view controller .

*note -

> Use this method to process incoming remote notifications for your app.
>   Unlike the application:didReceiveRemoteNotification: method, which is
>   called only when your app is running in the foreground, the system
>   calls this method when your app is running in the foreground or
>   background. In addition, if you enabled the remote notifications
>   background mode, the system launches your app (or wakes it from the
>   suspended state) and puts it in the background state when a push
>   notification arrives. However, the system does not automatically
>   launch your app if the user has force-quit it. In that situation, the
>   user must relaunch your app or restart the device before the system
>   attempts to launch your app automatically again.

Thanks.

Comment: We have issues when push is received in background.

Comment: In foreground, we are displaying `UIAlertView`, so thats not a problem for us

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this but I guess this app delegate method will solve your problem.

`application:handleActionWithIdentifier:forRemoteNotification:withResponseInfo:completionHandler:`

This method is called when your app has been activated by selecting an action from a remote notification.

The `userInfo` dictionary parameter contains information related to the remote notification.

For more information see apple documentation

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios//documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:handleActionWithIdentifier:forRemoteNotification:withResponseInfo:completionHandler:

Comment: This method is available from 8.0 onwards, our min version is 7.0

Answer (score 0):

This issue is bound to happen as you are handle notification in background, so by the time you try to launch your app from notification centre your app is already prepared to show previously received notifications.

So to fix your issue you should

1. Check and decide for latest or tapped notification or which ever make sense to show in `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler` or `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` as depending on app state these delegate get called for notification
2. Check for already shown viewController on app launch. If yes remove them and show latest or tapped notification.

   ```
   UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;

   UIViewController* topViewController = [navigationController visibleViewController];

   if ([topViewController isKindOfClass:[Excercise class]])
   {
       [topViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
   }
   ```

// launch relevant notification VC after.

Answer (score 0):

You can use different app states.

```
    func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)
    {
        if ( application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.Active)
        {
            // App is foreground and notification is recieved,
            // Show a alert.
        }
        else if( application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.Background)
        {
            // App is in background and notification is received, 
            // You can fetch required data here don't do anything with UI.
        }
        else if( application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.Inactive)
        {
           // App came in foreground by used clicking on notification, 
           // Use userinfo for redirecting to specific view controller.
        }

    }
```